# How to use existing PHP header generation class function to populate a twig template

Tags: symfony, twig

In the existing application, there is a function that dynamically generates the header using classes.

```
 use GLOBALNAMESPACE\Core\Header;
```

Then in the body, we use

```
<header>
  <title>My Page</title>
    <?php Header::setupHeader('[common],[reporthelper]') ?>
</header>
```

This would build all the headers like this when the page is rendered in the browser.

```
<header>
    <title>My Page</title> 

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/openemr/public/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css?v=44" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/openemr/public/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css?v=44" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/openemr/public/assets/jquery-datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css?v=44" type="text/css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="/openemr/public/assets/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?v=44"</script>
```

In my template file, I tried.

```
{%  
     include GLOBALNAMESPACE\\Core\\Header::setupHeader('[common],[reporthelper]')
 %}
```

This failed. Is there a way to include PHP classes?

UPDATE:

As suggested, created the HeaderExtension class in the twig directory.

```
Twig\HeaderExtension
```

Inside the file is this code:

```
 namespace Twig;

 use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;

class HeaderExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
public function getFunctions() {
    return [
        new TwigFunction(
            'header_setup',
            [OpenEMR\Core\Header::class, 'Header']
        ),
        // add more if needed
    ];
  }
}
```

In the method added

```
    $loader = new FilesystemLoader('../../templates/financialreports/insurance');
    $twig = new Environment($loader, [
        'cache' => 'C:\tempt',
    ]);

    return $twig->render('summaryinsurancepaid.html.twig', [
    'header' => new HeaderExtension(),
    'name' => 'Fabien Roger']);
```

Now, there are no error messages. However, the desired results are not achieved.
There seems to be a call to the setupHeader() missing. 
In the new TwigFunction 'header_setup' is defined as a class called in the global namespace to the header. 
But there is nothing that calls the class method setupHeader() where I can add the array  setupHeader(['common'],['reporthelper']). Passing in the array would bring back the desired results.

In the example on this page https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html.

They are using TwigFilter and not the TwigFunction to bring in a class at runtime. 
I changed this line, from this

```
 'header' => new HeaderExtension()
```

to this.

```
 'header' => new HeaderExtension('header_setup'),
```

No errors but no header either. So, I changed the template from this.

```
{{ header }}
```

To this:

```
{{ header(setupHeader(['common'],['reporthelper'])) }}
```

No error messages and no header either.
End of update.

Comment: how many functions do you want to expose? if it's just a handful, you can just provide them all via a twig extension, which is explained well enough in the twig docs https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#creating-an-extension ... okay, not well enough, but the parameters are essentially 1. name of function in twig, 2. callable, so like `[Header::class, 'setup']`

Comment: the number o functions to expose will vary based on what is called in the array. I see that twig is looking in the template folder for another HTML file. It is not following the PHP namespace.

Comment: Here is the final code for what I was trying to achieve https://github.com/openemr/openemr/pull/2731/commits/edbfc7a637560c5498c5489f80a9f218189c9ddf

Comment: you should still omit the line `'header' => new HeaderExtension('header_setup'),` in your twig render call. ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depending on the logic your `Header` does provide - especially regarding the output it creates - there are different approaches:

#### expose select `Header` methods via twig functions

```
namespace App\Twig;

class HeaderExtension extends \Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension {
    public function getFunctions() {
        return [
            new \Twig\TwigFunction(
                'header_setup', 
                [GLOBALNAMESPACE\Core\Header::class, 'setupAssets']
            ),
            // add more if needed
        ];
    }
}
```

and then use it in your template as

```
{{ header_setup('[common],[reporthelper]') }}
```

#### expose `Header`'s static functions via one twig function

A slight workaround could be another approach almost the same TwigFunction as before, but using:

```
new \Twig\TwigFunction('header', function($func, ...$args) {
    return call_user_func_array([GLOBALNAMESPACE\Core\Header::class, $func], $args);
}
```

which then would allow:

```
{{ header('setupAssets', '[common],[reporthelper]') }}
```

which obviously is a weirder syntax. you could go one step further

#### expose all class/instance functions

```
new \Twig\TwigFunction('call', function($class, $func, ...$args) {
    return call_user_func_array([$class, $func], $args);
}
```

and then use as:

```
{{ call('GLOBALNAMESPACE\\Core\\Header', 'setupAssets', '[common],[reporthelper]') }}
```

(which obviously poses an increased risk in security, if someone is able to edit templates, since now you can call all static functions anywhere...)

#### rewrite `Header` into something more beautiful

I assume some if not all of `Header`'s functionality is quite basic and could be expressed as a twig template itself, like ...

```
{% set targets = targets ?? ['common'] %}{# <-- defaults for every template? #}
{% if 'common' in targets %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/openemr/public/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css?v=44" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/openemr/public/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css?v=44" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/openemr/public/assets/jquery-datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css?v=44" type="text/css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="/openemr/public/assets/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?v=44"></script> 
{% endif %}
{% if 'reporthelper' in targets %}
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/openemr/public/assets/reporthelper/..."></script>
{% endif %}
```

and so on. However, I'm quite sure if the functionality you're looking for may be available via [webpack encore](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html)

#### update: how to add a twig extension to your symfony project & use it

assuming you're not just using symfony components (in which case the following will not apply), there are several ways how this is supposed to go:

**1. actually extending twig**

extending twig works in symfony by [adding `twig.extension` to your service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html#register-an-extension-as-a-service) (i.e. your twig extension), so, in your services yaml (be careful about matching the indentation with spaces as needed):

```
services:
    App\Twig\HeaderExtension:
        tags: ['twig.extension']
```

if you don't want this extension to be globally available, you can use symfony's dependency injection to fetch the twig service and add the extension

```
public function yourRouteAction(
    \Twig\Environment $twig
    /* your other parameters */
) {
    $twig->addExtension(new HeaderExtension());
    
    // don't *have* to use $twig here, symfony provides the very
    // same twig environment wherever it's referenced. this is not true
    // if you create one on the fly with new Twig...
    return $this->render(...);
```

just to be explicit about this: *adding the extension provides the function in twig, you do NOT have to add it in the render-call at all!*

**2. fixing your extension / usage**

Now that you actually added the extension *as an extension* and not just as a variable you have to manually add every time, there will be a function available:

```
{{ header_setup(...) }}
```

as I already wrote, you have to provide a callable as a second argument to the TwigFunction constructor. Since the last time you changed what you wanted to call, so I updated my answer. The structure of a callable is: `[classname, functionname]` for static calls, so in your case: `[Header::class, 'setupAssets']`. that means, your call *in twig* is then

```
{{ header_setup(a) }} {{ header_setup(b,c,d) }} {{ header_setup([e,f]) }}
```

which will translate into

```
Header::setupAssets(a) // and
Header::setupAssets(b,c,d) // and
Header::setupAssets([e,f])
```

respectively.

this also assumes, that your Header::setupAssets() *returns* the text, so that it is inserted at the correct position. I'm not very certain how twigs echos stuff, but if your Header echos everything right away instead of returning it, which your code suggests, you might have to use output buffering to catch it:

```
        new \Twig\TwigFunction(
            'header_setup', 
            function(...$args) {
                ob_start();
                call_user_func_array(
                   [GLOBALNAMESPACE\Core\Header::class, 'setupAssets'],
                   $args
                ); // if Header::setupAssets echoes directly, it will be caught
                return ob_get_clean(); // returns caught stuff
            }
        ),
```

Comment: Thank you for putting a lot of thought into this and I will update my request with more information. I did follow the advice and I get a new error now.

Comment: I really can't take a chance on making something beautiful as other pages depend on this class. I am trying not to build a whole new class but use what is existing if at all possible.

Comment: @user1794918 This will take a bit more effort to fix, will update my answer later. let's say you have a misconception about how symfony and/or twig work. maybe you'll find out, before I answer ;o/

Comment: I had to go do some studying to understand the answer. I need to learn more about the structure of the existing application. I found the services.yml file and inserted the code. As I build it out based on the answer you have given. I will report back once I know its a go or no go situation.

Comment: It is working! The function does return text and populates the header with the location of the public assets. So now if the assets change. The page will auto-update from the central class as it is supposed to do.